# Pass Type to method?

Tags: c#

I need some help being pointed in the right direction. I would like to create a method that can process different types. I need to pass these types in somehow and use them somehow. Any guidance on this would be great. Here is the method, where "TypeINeedToPassIn" is, yes you guessed correct, the type i need to pass in:

```
public static object MatchAccountType(string acctTypeStr)
{
    var acctTypes = SharedUtils.GetEnumValues<TypeINeedToPassIn>();

    foreach (TypeINeedToPassIn acctType in acctTypes)
    {
        if (acctTypeStr.ToUpper() == acctType.ToString().ToUpper())
        {
            return acctType;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

TIA

Comment: Please take a look at this MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Comment: 'Generics' are built for this purpose.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to reinvent [Enum.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: So you're doing enum value lookup by name? Why not use the (generic) `Enum.TryParse<>` method? There's an overload that ignores case.

Comment: I'm working with some older existing code, i'm open to any suggested improvements though.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this:

        public static T MatchAccountType<T>(string acctTypeStr)
        {
            return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), acctTypeStr, true);
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your method generic to accept a type parameter:

```
public static object MatchAccountType<T>(string acctTypeStr)
```

That type could then be used in the code within the method:

```
public static object MatchAccountType<T>(string acctTypeStr)
{
    var acctTypes = SharedUtils.GetEnumValues<T>();

    foreach (T acctType in acctTypes)
    {
        if (acctTypeStr.ToUpper() == acctType.ToString().ToUpper())
        {
            return acctType;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you need to interact more with that type in the code within the method, or put restrictions on what types can be used, there's [more to it that you can investigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).  But just requiring a type parameter can be done by simply making it a generic method.

Comment: You can also type the return type. `public static T MatchAccountType<T>`. And maybe restrict `T` to be a `struct`?

Comment: @LeonardoChaia: Good point, it *may* be likely that the `object` return type isn't what the user wants either and is just a vestige of previous attempts to make this work.

Comment: Thank you guys, this was exactly what i am looking for.